# Google calendar API private events

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar API for an android application for booking rooms. The application doesn't have the option to make an event private but I want to visualize private events created from Google Calendar so that people can't book a room with private event in it. I managed to do this, but when I change the visibility of a private event to public or default from Google Calendar, the request still returns private visibility. I think that happens because the access role returned from the request is reader(when it is owner, everything works fine), but I don't know what to do about it.

[This is the events information with the access role variable.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4HG6.png)

[image]

[This is the request I make.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQX2G.png)

[image]

[And this is the result from the request for this event.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLrt6.png)

[image]

Comment: How are you updating the event?  Please include the code you are using to update the event.  **NOT** a picture of your code

Comment: I'm updating the visibility through Google Calendar, not my code, because I only want to visualize private events, not create them in my app. And then the request takes the events from Google Calendar.

Comment: Hey, have you ever resolved this? I have the same problem (using Go package).